# Get data from row inside model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to set a morphed model dynamically based upon the row:

On the model I set it inside:

```
public function getMorphClass()
{
}
```

How can I get the item `type` from the row in the query? Something like:

```
public function getMorphClass()
{
    return $this->type; //currently null but want row's type value
}
```

Comment: I'm kinda confused what you mean with "row's type value" is it the morph class column or something custom?

Comment: Each row in my table has a column called type, how can I get this inside my model?

Comment: if you are in the model that corresponds to the row $this->type should return that, that is why i think it is a little confusing :)

Comment: But it doesnt return it.

Comment: `Model::find($id)->getMorphClass();` doesn't work?

Comment: That's not what i'm trying to do, I want `type` inside the model

Comment: getMorphClass() is called on the model, so if that works you have type inside your model :) I think some parts to the question is missing since that doesn't work. Describe tables and all your models. Because this should work.

Comment: Well, you'll need the corresponding instance first. I mentioned that just for debugging porpouse, if it returns null, it will return null inside the model too, but if it returns the value, maybe you have not retrieved the record when you tryied to use it inside the model

Comment: It's a really simple question, I just need to get an attribute inside a model - how can I do this?

Comment: Clearly not since it is not working and the information you given us is very sparse. Two people ask you why this is not working, "Model::find($id)->getMorphClass();" and you say that is not what you want. This code, use type from within your model. Then please explain us why this is wrong.

Comment: Inside a model, how can I access a model's own attribute from inside a relationship definition?

Comment: Show us how you use the relationship and how you defined it that is not in the question. You are probably running into something being called on your model, while it is not bound to a concrete instance of a row.

Comment: Looking at it, it does work, if the relationship is not eager loaded, fails when eager loaded. Anyone know a fix to eager load and still maintain access to a row's attributes?

Comment: Inside a relationship definition? Maybe if you retrieve the model record first, a then load the relationship `$model->load('relationship')` the relationship function is called and the `type` property is already filled (not tested and looks weird). If you want some kind of condition on the relationship, based on the `type` property, i think you should do it in the query. Something like `whereColumn` clause maybe usefull

Comment: If I retrieve the model first then I cannot eager load. I'm actually thinking this is not possible. You mention, do it in the query, do you have an example how a polymorphic relationship can be defined inside a query?